How to design a Hardware Solution for Duplicating Mouse Events to multiple devices
I'm looking for a solution where I can use a single USB mouse to control two devices simultaneously. I understand there are software solutions for computers, but I specifically need a hardware-based solution for this task.
I didn't find any solution, the closest one was a KVM switch, but didn't find any that can duplicate the mouse behaviour. It can only switch between both.
It can't have any software for the solution because the second device I want to connect to it's not a computer. It's a device that sits in the middle of the computer and the mouse and modifies mouse events before reaching the PC.
Project Goals:
Duplicate Mouse Events: The mouse movements and clicks should be mirrored on both devices at the same time. ( I understand now that the devices will poll the mouse events at different times and it's an accepted limitation).
Hardware-Based Solution: I need this to be a purely hardware solution without relying on network-based software.
I am a software developer but never worked with microcontrollers and have no knowledge of electronics. I can seek help if a solution is achievable.
Do you think a solution for this is truly achievable? Would it cost too much time (like months)?

@All - Although well-intentioned, comments here have became a discussion and (at least partial) answers, neither of which is an allowed use of comments. Unsurprisingly, this is getting flagged. Therefore comments so far have been moved to chat & should be continued there. Here is the chatroom link..

As this bulk moving of comments to chat can only be done once per question, any further comments posted here may be deleted without notice. Keep it in chat now, please! || Any improvement / clarification to the question decided during the chat, should be made via an [edit], not as a comment. If the question is reopened and someone has enough information to post an answer, please answer it as usual. TY

There's no guarantee that sending the same mouse movement data to each PC will always result in the same mouse pointer position on each PC - it's possible that they'll drift over time. You may need to occasionally 'zero' them by moving the pointer into a corner and 'past the edge of the screen' to get them to sync back up.

@brhans - Please post that comment in the chat instead, as requested above. TY

Mice do not emit "events"; that is a software concept that the mouse driver converts the change of state into, to notify software about it.
Instead, all USB devices essentially work by answering requests by the host, whose job is to regularly poll the USB devices. In human interface device parlance, the mouse responds with a "report".
Now, USB is strictly a tree: there's one root of a tree, and that is the host controller in the device you connect the mouse to. A USB device simply can't work with two hosts. And USB hubs only work in that one direction, too: there's one "upstream" port going towards the host, and one or multiple downstream ports, going to USB devices.
So, whatever shape the device you need takes, its functionality must be to track the state of the mouse, and give reports as if it was a mouse itself.
Such devices used to exist, and they're not incredibly hard to conceive if you limit the kind of things your hosts are and do:
A sniffer could simply sit and listen on the "direct" connection between the mouse and host A, and take note of all the reports that the mouse sends to A in reponse to requests from A. When B requests, it would respond with a copy of the latest report it saw.
This still requires that the device knows how to "act a mouse" towards host B. Specifically, a mouse with the same capabilities as the actual mouse; so it would also have to listen to the initialization between A and mouse before it can become visible to B.
The intuitive thing here is to implement the USB sniffing (A<->mouse) part in an FPGA, and because you already have that at hand, also implement the USB device logic (for connecting to B) in that FPGA. Sniffing is easy, you just look for the setup and report packets, decode their content and respond with that when asked the same questions. The more annoying part is implementing a full USB device that can enumerate on the bus when ready, can respond to configuration requests, deals with bus resets etc.
Mice belong to the very few devices that still work at USB low speed; this might be the saving grace here: you don't have to implement a USB mouse sniffer + mouse decoy device in an FPGA by writing digital logic descriptions (e.g. verilog, vhdl, amaranth); the state machines needed for a fully functional USB device can indeed be a bit annoying (but manageable (example in gateware; just not something you'll in a week do if you're not familiar with hardware design an USB), so it's nice that microcontrollers ship sufficiently advanced integrated USB peripherals to take that load off your shoulders.
So, a prototype would look like this:

an FPGA-based USB configuration packet and report sniffer
a sufficiently capable microcontroller with a USB peripheral embeddeded (so, probably, an arm cortex-M4 or something, no need to be cheap, more need to be easy)
the gateware to make 1. work and send the data in a data format of your choosing via a very simple bus (SPI, probably) to 2.
the firmware needed to present 2. as exactly the "cloned" mouse to the second host as soon as a configuration USB packet has been sniffed, and which responds to requests from the host with the data from the last report that it has sniffed.
This will have to entail programming the SPI peripheral and the DMA engine in a way that ensures that the report data read by the USB part of your firmware is never overwritten while it's being used.

I won't lean out the window with an effort estimate without having worked with you on a close-to-the-metal project before. But: I have to say that I think that simply building a device from a microcontroller that simply "plays back" a scripted sequence of reports is much more sensible, because

you don't need an actual mouse to compare differences; on the contrary, something reproducible is much more useful. And it seems you don't need immediate reproduction, you'll want to record what the unmodified and modified mouse does, and then compare these offline
it's much much easier to write a simple USB mouse-type device that just plays back records from integrated memory – in fact, implementing a simple HID is often part of the examples for USB firmware development that microcontroller vendors offer.

